# mysql starting and stopping every 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

Mysql is starting and stopping every 15 seconds on my MAC. In the console it shows /tmp/mysql.sock is Permission denied. What unix command can I run to make sure every folder related to mysql is read/write.  Its for dev so I don't care if anyone hacks it or screws it up.... just tired of putting in my password everytime I click a folder and need to solve this mysql issue.

TIA

Comment: How did you install the mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't endorse the "just open everything to everyone!" strategy, the answer to your question is `chmod`; check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), with particular consideration of its `-r` recursive flag.